# Hibernate and EclipseLink Providers

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, eclipselink

I have a Hibernate running in my project and I am trying to set it up to be switchable to EclipseLink. I have added all EclipseLink classes in Maven, but it seems that they are not running at all. When I try to run the project, it ends up with:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
    No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
```

My *persistence.xml* file: https://gist.github.com/1676280

The *pom.xml* file with the dependencies: https://gist.github.com/1676282

Once I switch the providers in the persistence.xml back to Hibernate, everything works correctly.

Comment: I don't think that will be an easy task switching JPA implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one significant issue and a couple of minor problems in your persistence.xml.

The big issue is the your persistence unit is named "org.knyttl" but the error message says persistence unit "test" can't be found. If you're looking for "test" and the pu is "org.knyttl" then you're not going to find anything. :)

The minor issues are that you have a couple of the EclipseLink properties misnamed. "javax.persistence.target-database" should be "[eclipselink.target-database](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_for_Logging)" and "javax.persistence.logging.level" should be "[eclipselink.logging.level](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_for_Session.2C_Target_Database_and_Target_Application_Server)".

Shaun

Comment: The "test" and "org.knyttl" was just a typo when posting the question. Unfortunately the minor issues did not fix the problem.

Comment: If your persistence unit names in the persistence.xml and in the call to createEntityManagerFactory() match then I'd bet EclipseLink is not on your classpath.  To debug this you can step through the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory code and watch it hunting for JPA providers.  It locates them by trying to load all the META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider files on the classpath.